# How to order X axis by YearMonth at Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I use the current version of http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Air+quality
My issue is that I want to create a plot that is ordered by monthly aggregates of different features that plotted on multiple graphs

**YearMonth Creation for X Axis**

```
INPUT:
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Time'].astype(str)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(df['DateTime'].iloc[:2])

OUTPUT:
0   2004-11-23 19:00:00
1   2004-11-23 20:00:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]



INPUT:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y')

df['Year'] = df['DateTime'].map(lambda x: x.year)
print(df['Year'].iloc[:2])

OUTPUT:
0    2004
1    2004
Name: Year, dtype: int64



INPUT:
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime).dt.to_period('m')
print(df['YearMonth'].iloc[:2])

OUTPUT:
0    2004-11
1    2004-11
Name: YearMonth, dtype: period[M]
```

Goal [project](https://github.com/wei-yuan/AirQualityUCI/blob/master/2019_March_KKBOX_air_quality_forecast_EDA.ipynb) has same results, format

**My Plotting**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,60))
#fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(30, 60), dpi=100)

gasList = ['CO_GT', 'C6H6_GT', 'Nox_GT', 'NO2_GT']
for i, col in enumerate(gasList, start=1):
    plt.subplot(len(showList), 1, i)    
    sns.pointplot(x='YearMonth', y=col, hue='Year', data=df)
    plt.title(col, y=0.5, loc='right')
    #axes.set_xticks(year_month_day)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Ideal plotting**

I am trying to achieve the same as this [projects](https://github.com/wei-yuan/AirQualityUCI/blob/master/2019_March_KKBOX_air_quality_forecast_EDA.ipynb)

[image]

**Tried to do to Solve the problem**

- If I would just use DateTime than it works to order the dates but that makes the plot to densely populated
- I have the same data format that creates the YearMonth

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9357 entries, 0 to 9356
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------        --------------  -----         
 0   Date          9357 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   Time          9357 non-null   object        
 2   CO_GT         9357 non-null   float64       
 3   PT08_S1_CO    9357 non-null   float64       
 4   C6H6_GT       9357 non-null   float64       
 5   PT08_S2_NMHC  9357 non-null   float64       
 6   Nox_GT        9357 non-null   float64       
 7   PT08_S3_Nox   9357 non-null   float64       
 8   NO2_GT        9357 non-null   float64       
 9   PT08_S4_NO2   9357 non-null   float64       
 10  PT08_S5_O3    9357 non-null   float64       
 11  T             9357 non-null   float64       
 12  RH            9357 non-null   float64       
 13  AH            9357 non-null   float64       
 14  DateTime      9357 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 15  Year          9357 non-null   int64         
 16  YearMonth     9357 non-null   period[M]     
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(12), int64(1), object(1), period[M](1)
memory usage: 1.3+ MB
```

- His data set's time formatting was Y m d mine was m d Y but I have changed back to the the same as his
- I have tried to use seaborn's order parameter. It loads for a long time but doesn't gives anything back.

```
col_one_list = df['YearMonth'].tolist()
plt.figure(figsize=(30,60))

gasList = ['CO_GT', 'C6H6_GT', 'Nox_GT', 'NO2_GT']
for i, col in enumerate(gasList, start=1):
    plt.subplot(len(showList), 1, i)    
    sns.pointplot(x='YearMonth', y=col, hue='Year', data=df, order = col_one_list )
    plt.title(col, y=0.5, loc='right')

plt.show()
```

- I have created a list myself of uniq values but that have also crashed. OUTPUT: correct YearMonth-s x axis ticks, correct plot external elements, but no data points plotted.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,60))

col_two_list = ['2004-03','2004-04', '2004-05', '2004-06', '2004-07', '2004-08', '2004-09', '2004-10', '2004-11','2004-12', '2005-01','2005-02','2005-03', '2005-04']

gasList = ['CO_GT', 'C6H6_GT', 'Nox_GT', 'NO2_GT']
for i, col in enumerate(gasList, start=1):
    plt.subplot(len(showList), 1, i)    
    sns.pointplot(x='YearMonth', y=col, hue='Year', data=df, order = col_two_list )
    plt.title(col, y=0.5, loc='right')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

When you generate your *pointplot*, pass **sorted** DataFrame (by
*YearMonth*) and the printout should be just as you wish.

Without the above sort the picture is as you presented (wrong).

## Long answer

I prepared a test input file, for just 2 columns, as follows:

```
DateTime    CO_GT  C6H6_GT
2004-11-01  2.7    12.4
2004-12-01  2.6    10.6
2004-10-01  3.0    13.8
2005-01-01  2.0    9.0
2005-02-01  2.2    8.0
2004-03-01  2.2    10.0
2004-09-01  2.2    12.0
2005-03-01  2.0    8.6
2004-04-01  2.1    10.2
2004-05-01  1.95   10.5
2004-06-01  1.85   10.4
2004-07-01  1.7    10.5
2005-04-01  1.3    4.5
2004-08-01  1.4    6.8
```

Then I read it, converting *DateTime* column to *datetime* type (as early
as possible, i.e. just on reading):

```
df = pd.read_fwf('Input.csv', widths=[12, 7, 7], parse_dates=[0])
```

The first step is to create "auxiliary" columns:

```
df['Year'] = df.DateTime.dt.year
df['YearMonth'] = df.DateTime.dt.to_period('m')
```

And to generate the picture, I ran:

```
gasList = ['CO_GT', 'C6H6_GT']
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
for i, col in enumerate(gasList, start=1):
    plt.subplot(len(gasList), 1, i)    
    sns.pointplot(x='YearMonth', y=col, hue='Year', data=df.sort_values('DateTime'))
    plt.title(col, y=0.5, loc='right')
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]